# Issue with Android Studio Android App, header bar

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

I have in-depth experience with Android Apps, but primarily developed my previous Android Apps using Eclipse and the Google Developer Tools, I actually started with Moto-Dev Studio in 2012, but that was discontinued and afterwards I moved to using Eclipse, now I have started using Android Studio.

I created an example ASP.NET MVC web application for book and author information, using SQL Server database and hosted on Azure, at domain http://www.bookz-and-authorz.net. I want to create an Android App using the same database data, with a .NET Web API REST webservice on the backend accessing the same SQL Server database as the web application. I plan to store the source code for the Books android app in my github repo, with an MIT license, to help me get new software work and new freelance work.

I want the name of the Android app to be Books_Android, so that will also be the name of the Github repo, so people viewing the repo online will know it is for an Android app.

I want the Android app to have a photo of books that can be slide left to get to the main menu of the app. I already found a photo, and started on the app with Android Studio, but for some reason Android Studio puts a green header at the top of the first screen of the app with the words "Books_Android", I do not want that header to be there, only the image with slide left action, but for the life of me cannot find how to get rid of the green header bar, I searched through the XML files and did not find anything, note screenshots. I am certain there is a simple fix for this issue, but have no idea how to implement it.

[image: Virtual Device Display of APP]

[image: Android Studio]

[image: Android Studio]

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a style:

```
<style 
    name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" 
    parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

and then apply the theme to your activity:

```
<activity
   android:name=".MyActivity"
   android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" 
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a simple solution to this problem, in Android Studio 3.5, the most current version as of this date. All You have to do is open the AndroidManifest.xml file, and choose one of the code complete options for the android:theme attribute, basically the same answer as Bruno submitted last year, but he did not mention that the changes should be in the Manifest file, AndroidManifest.xml.

[image: Android Studio Manifests File]